# How to submit a form and download the formatted information

Tags: php, html, download, form-submit

Okay, so I have a form. I want to be able to enter information and when I hit the submit button, download the information in a formatted matter.

For example, here is a basic form

```
<html>
<body>
        <form action="submit.php" method="post">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                <td>Week of:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="week"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                            <td>Monday:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mon"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tuesday:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="tue"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Wednesday:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="wed"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thursday:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="thur"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Friday:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fri"></td>
            </tr>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the submission page.

```
<html>
<body>
Your schedule for the week of <?php echo $_POST["week"]; ?> !<br>
Monday <?php echo $_POST["mon"]; ?> <br>
Tuesday <?php echo $_POST["tue"]; ?> <br>
Wednesday <?php echo $_POST["wed"]; ?> <br>
Thursday <?php echo $_POST["thur"]; ?> <br>
Friday <?php echo $_POST["fri"]; ?> <br>
</body>
</html>
```

The submission page displays the information into a different format. How can I get the information downloaded into a text document looking like this?

Comment: What exactly is the question here? You have all components: a form, uploading, creating some output. What do you miss?!?

Comment: looking like what?.. i think you forgot the something there!!

Comment: adamj answered. I didn't miss anything, you didn't read it very carefully. I am trying to download the information. This just displays it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

You need to format your data in your preferred format after which you are able to do something similar to this:

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```